# OnClickListener on cardViews not working properly Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-cardview

I've been having this problem for a couple of days, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
I am trying to add a cardView with some Views inside, to a LinearLayout, one for each note that I have in the DB. So far no problem, the issue is that I also want to add an OnClickListener to each of those cardViews that I am creating programmatically. So that each time the CardView is clicked it expands or collapses.
The problem is that when doing so, all the CardViews share the OnClickListener, and when clicking on one, all the CardViews expand, I want only the one I'm clicking to expand.

I hope I have explained myself, I share part of the code.

```
for (nota in notas) {


                    val card = CardView(view.context)
                    val note = TextView(view.context)
                    val date = TextView(view.context)
                    val lLHor = LinearLayout(view.context)
                    val lLVer = LinearLayout(view.context)
                    val im = ImageView(view.context)

                    lLVer.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f
                    )


                    with(im) {
                        setImageDrawable(
                            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                                view.context,
                                R.drawable.ic_arrow_down
                            )
                        )
                        foregroundGravity = Gravity.END
                        layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0f
                        )
                    }



                    lLHor.orientation = (LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)
                    lLVer.orientation = (LinearLayout.VERTICAL)



                    with(note) {
                        setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#252323"))
                        text = nota.getString("Nota")
                        textSize = 20F
                        layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f
                        )
                    }


                    with(date) {
                        setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#252323"))
                        text = nota.getString("Fecha")
                        textSize = 20F
                        layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0f
                        )
                    }


                    card.layoutParams = lP
                    card.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))

                    card.setOnClickListener {

                        cardEC(card, im)
                    }

                    lLVer.addView(date)
                    lLVer.addView(note)
                    lLHor.addView(lLVer)
                    lLHor.addView(im)
                    card.addView(lLHor)
                    linearNotas.addView(card)



                }

private fun cardEC(cardView: CardView, imageView: ImageView) {
    val height: Int =
        TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 28F, resources.displayMetrics)
            .toInt()

    val layPar = cardView.layoutParams

    if (cardView.layoutParams.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        layPar.height = height
        cardView.layoutParams = layPar
        imageView.setImageDrawable(
            view?.let {
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    it.context,
                    R.drawable.ic_arrow_down
                )
            })
    } else {
        layPar.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        cardView.layoutParams = layPar
        imageView.setImageDrawable(
            view?.let {
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    it.context,
                    R.drawable.ic_arrow_up
                )
            })

    }

}
```

**Edit**: I add images to see the problem well

[Card before press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN01T.jpg)

Then when i press any cardView

[Cards after press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdfpu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I "solved"**
Although I still don't understand why the problem occurred, I found a way to bypass it. I leave the solution I found in case it helps someone.
Based on the help @DavudDavudov gave me.
I keep the height of the CardView as WrapContent. When I create the TextView that contains the note, I set the View.Gone visibility to it. Then in the cardEC function I change the visibility of the TextView to View.Visible or View.Gone depending on how it was. And since the CardView is in WrapContent, plus the animateLayoutChanges It works perfectly, it gives the sensation of opening a drop-down menu. I copy part of the code in case it helps.

```
 with(note) {
                        setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#252323"))
                        text = nota.getString("Nota")
                        textSize = 20F
                        layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f
                        )
                        visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                    val noteContent = mutableListOf(note)
                    cardEC(card, im, noteContent)

private fun cardEC(cardView: CardView, imageView: ImageView, noteContent: MutableList<TextView>) {

    cardView.setOnClickListener {

        for (textView in noteContent){
            if (textView.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
                textView.visibility = View.GONE
                imageView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_arrow_down, null))
            }else{
                textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_arrow_up, null))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set note visibility to GONE when card is not expanded
and set height of card view to 63 when the card is expanded

MainActivity

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.testapp.entity.Note
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val notas = arrayListOf<Note>()
        for (i in 0..20) {
            notas.add(Note(i, "note$i"))
        }
        val linearNotas = main_lp
        for (nota in notas) {


            val card = CardView(this)
            val note = TextView(this)
            val date = TextView(this)
            val lLHor = LinearLayout(this)
            val lLVer = LinearLayout(this)
            val im = ImageView(this)

            lLVer.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f
            )


            with(im) {
                setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        context,
                        R.drawable.ic_baseline_5g_24
                    )
                )
                foregroundGravity = Gravity.END
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0f
                )
            }



            lLHor.orientation = (LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)
            lLVer.orientation = (LinearLayout.VERTICAL)



            with(note) {
                setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#252323"))
                text = nota.title
                textSize = 20F
                visibility = View.GONE
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f
                )
            }


            with(date) {
                setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#252323"))
                text = "date ${nota.title}"
                textSize = 20F
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0f
                )
            }


            card.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))

            card.setOnClickListener {

                cardEC(card, im,note)
            }

            lLVer.addView(date)
            lLVer.addView(note)
            lLHor.addView(lLVer)
            lLHor.addView(im)
            card.addView(lLHor)
            linearNotas.addView(card)

        }
    }


    private fun cardEC(cardView: CardView, imageView: ImageView,note:TextView) {
        val height: Int =
            TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 63f, resources.displayMetrics)
                .toInt()

        val layPar = cardView.layoutParams

        if (cardView.layoutParams.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
            note.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            layPar.height = height
            cardView.layoutParams = layPar
            imageView.setImageDrawable(

                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    this,
                    R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_24
                )
            )
        } else {
            note.visibility= View.GONE
            layPar.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            cardView.layoutParams = layPar
            imageView.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    this,
                    R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_drop_up_24
                )
            )

        }


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_lp"
    />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I had that idea, I assigned an unused ID to each cardBox, and then added the OnClickListener looking for the CardView by ID but nothing, same problem.

Comment: you can set note visibility to GONE when card is not expanded as I edited my answer included the code

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried your code but it doesn't work, it makes the cardviews behave strangely, but even so, they all kept expanding at the same time when pressing on any one

Comment: It is so strange though it works well for me can you say please what is the parent layout of view?

Comment: Please take attention and try the code. full code is shown in answer

Comment: I made a new test project with your code, it worked flawlessly. So I tried my version of "cardEC", it worked perfectly. So the problem is not there. I have to say that I am using AnimateLayoutChanges and layoutTransition.enableTransitionType in the LinearLayout, but even using this in the test project it still works fine, so this is not the problem either. Right now I'm pretty lost, I don't know what causes the problem. The problem is not that the CardView does not display correctly, nor that it does not animate. The problem is that pressing one activates all of them.

Comment: Here a picture of the Component Tree. Cards are added to the highlighted LinearLayout
[link](https://i.ibb.co/B6CXkSK/1.png)

Comment: I kinda solved it, Check the answer i posted. Thank you very much for your help @DavudDavudov